# Want to Transmit a live feed from Cellphone to Custom Application over bluetooth

Tags: c#, java, mobile, bluetooth, camera

Hi I'm writing a POS(Point of sale system) for a small Computer shop and I would like to try to incorporate a small system that the manager can use. The system should be able to send its camera feed from a java application and a phone to my application on his PC over blue-tooth so that he can scan bar codes into the system from his phone. The program on the desktop is written in c#. sorry if I left out any details, please ask if you do not completely understand what i am trying to do. Any advice on where to begin with this part of my project because I've tried Google but with so little knowledge on the subject I'm just getting confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not you use barcode scanner, there are plethora of api's on scanning barcode to pc

Answer (score 1):

Anyway my earlier  research on this topic, refer to the following links

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/embedded/aa714533.aspx
- http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/bluetoothdevelopment/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158662.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/codejunkie/archive/2008/09/13/bluetooth-device-control-development-using-c.aspx

This site has a number of applications that are developed specifically for bluetooth

- http://bluetooth.softalizer.com/

Note :

- It seems you are scanning a barcode image and transmitting via bluetooth, although it is not totally improper, but make sure the camera is of hi-resolution atleast 5 megapixel .

Comment: Thanks for the links going to start going through them now, I realize you can just use a bar code scanner but my client is asking me for this, he has his specific reasons why he needs this.

Comment: I've stubled upon an app that sends a mjpg video stream via IP, so i'm going to try and extract the barcodes from the stream, thanks again for your help, i've also decided to use a wireless connection instead.

Comment: pls. upvote if the suggestion was usefull and mark if it is the asnwer

Comment: Dont have the rep yet as this is the first time i found it necessary to regester, as soo as I gain the reputation I will upvote it!